# useState doesn't re-initialize after fetch

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to initialize a useState based on a variable user.x that is fetched from the data base but the problem is, useState will initialize before the fetch and not after the fetch. So the value in useState is always initialized as undefined.

```
function foo () {

const [user, setUsers] = useState([])    
        
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("Some URL to fetch from")
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then((result)=>{
            setUsers(result);
         })
},[])

const [check, setCheck] = useState(() => {
    if (user.x == "No") {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  });   


}
```

I know useEffect is what rerender the page and we can't use Axios because it messes with the other code. So is there a way to force useState to rerender after useEffect fetching or fetch without axios and useEffect?

Comment: 1. useEffect does not rerender the page; state changes do. 2. you use setUser in your fetch, so how is the fetch supposed to work if useState were to reinitilize after the fetch. 3. Use State only initializes on initial render, on subsequent renders it will not reinitialize (that's the whole point of state; to carry over information between rerenders)

Answer (score 0):

You could use another `useEffect` triggered by the changes in your `user` state variable like so:

```js
const [check, setCheck] = useState(False);
useEffect(() => {
    setCheck(user.x !== "No");
}, [user, setCheck]);
```

This effect depends on `user` so it triggers when that state changes and updates your `check` state.